# react router slug compared to part of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I started to experiment with react router, and dynamic matches.
I wanted to create a function which matches the slug of the URL to a slug in a JSON file.
 The error I get:
TypeError: Unable to get property 'slug' of undefined or null reference

I think that the 'Slug' of the url is undefined, but I am not sure on how to fix it.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqS50.png)

my code for routes.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/header/header.js';
import Home from './components/home/home.js';
import About from './components/about/about.js';
import NotFound from './components/notFound/notFound.js'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,  Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import PostPage from './components/postpage/postpage.js'
import posts from './files/data.json';

class Routes extends React.Component {
render(){
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/:slug" component={props => {
        const postt = posts.posts.filter (post => props.params.slug === post.slug)
        console.log(postt.length)
        return <PostPage post={postt} />
    } } />
    }}/>
    <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>

            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
}

export default Routes;
```

PostsPage.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

import Post from '../post/post.js'

const PostPage = (props) => (
            <div>
                 <Post {...props.post}/>
            </div>
);
export default PostPage;
```

and posts.js:

```js
import React from 'react'; 
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './post.css';

class Post extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div >
                <h2 className='subTitle'><Link to={`/post/${this.props.slug}`} className='link'>{this.props.title}</Link></h2>
                <p className='content'>{this.props.excerpt}</p>

            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Post;
```

If you made it this far thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

`slug` variable is given inside match props which you are missing.

```
<Route path="/:slug" render={props => {
        const postt = posts.posts.filter (post => props.match.params.slug === post.slug)
        console.log(postt.length)
        return <PostPage post={postt} />
    } } />
    }}/>
```

Also, do not inline `component` use a render function instead. From the docs:

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
>   children prop (below).

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: I tried props.match.params before, but I missed the render part

Comment: `props.match.params` is not working and gives the same error as before? @TeodorNedevski

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can get this fixed is by using `.find()` instead of `.filter()` like this :

```
 const postt = posts.find (post => props.match.params.slug === post.slug)
```

And then inside your `<Router />` make sure to send the rest of `{...props}` as well :

```
   <Route path="/:slug" component={props => {
        const postt = posts.find (post => props.match.params.slug === post.slug)
        console.log(postt.length)
        return <PostPage post={postt} {...props} />
    } } />
```